# Limit number of users per group on app

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

So I'm working on a mobile app that allows users to join groups. Groups are capped at a certain size. If a group has 1 slot left how do I prevent more than one user from joining the group at the same time? I am using MySQL for the database and a php web server to connect to the database. Something like this would be achievable with locks but I'm not sure how to do that with php/mysql when requests are being handled concurrently.

I couldn't find anything else on stack overflow with this but maybe I wasn't searching right.

Comment: how do you check the remaining places?does the whole slots number is saved with each row in database?

Comment: The number of people in each group and the total number is saved in the database so I can figure out how many slots are remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter whether you store the number of users in a group in a field or you determine this number on the fly using count() function in sql, use [select ...for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) with innodb table engine to lock the records from being accessed while you process the group membership application. Use explicit transactions for this ([start transaction - commit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

This way the 1st user's application locks the record(s) required for determining group membership number, therefore the 2nd user's application will wait until the 1st user's application completes.